# Row border with different number of columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am dynamically generating a table and each row can have different number of cells (tds). I want a divider type border between rows.

I tried to use border-top on td but since number of tds are different it wont work with td. Adding border-top to tr also doesnt work.

Issue: Current code generates border according to number of tds and desired result is with equal 100% length border irrespective of tds.

[image]

```css
.svlist >tbody> tr {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-top: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
}
.table>thead>tr>th, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>td {
    padding: 8px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #ecf0f1;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-borderless svlist">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th style='text-align: center;' colspan='3'>Control</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>apache2</td>
            <td>
                <div class='circle'></div>
                <div>Running</div>
            </td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='apache2' data-service_control='restart' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-repeat' aria-hidden='true'></span> Restart</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice disabled' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='apache2' data-service_control='start' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-off' aria-hidden='true'></span> Start</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='apache2' data-service_control='stop' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-stop' aria-hidden='true'></span> Stop</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>monit</td>
            <td>
                <div class='circle'></div>
                <div>Running</div>
            </td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='monit' data-service_control='restart' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-repeat' aria-hidden='true'></span> Restart</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='monit' data-service_control='start' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-off' aria-hidden='true'></span> Start</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice disabled' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='monit' data-service_control='stop' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-stop' aria-hidden='true'></span> Stop</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link uninstall_monit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#UninstallMonitModal' data-service='monit' data-service_control='uninstall' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle' aria-hidden='true'></span> Uninstall</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link open_monit' href='#' target='_blank'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home' aria-hidden='true'></span> Open</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>mysql</td>
            <td>
                <div class='circlered'></div>
                <div>Stopped</div>
            </td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='mysql' data-service_control='restart' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-repeat' aria-hidden='true'></span> Restart</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='mysql' data-service_control='start' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-off' aria-hidden='true'></span> Start</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice disabled' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='mysql' data-service_control='stop' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-stop' aria-hidden='true'></span> Stop</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>php5.6-fpm</td>
            <td>
                <div class='circle'></div>
                <div>Running</div>
            </td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='php5.6-fpm' data-service_control='restart' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-repeat' aria-hidden='true'></span> Restart</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice disabled' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='php5.6-fpm' data-service_control='start' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-off' aria-hidden='true'></span> Start</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='php5.6-fpm' data-service_control='stop' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-stop' aria-hidden='true'></span> Stop</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>php7.0-fpm</td>
            <td>
                <div class='circle'></div>
                <div>Running</div>
            </td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='php7.0-fpm' data-service_control='restart' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-repeat' aria-hidden='true'></span> Restart</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice disabled' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='php7.0-fpm' data-service_control='start' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-off' aria-hidden='true'></span> Start</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='php7.0-fpm' data-service_control='stop' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-stop' aria-hidden='true'></span> Stop</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>phpmyadmin</td>
            <td>
                <div class='circle'></div>
                <div>Running</div>
            </td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link uninstall_phpmyadmin' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#UninstallPhpmyadminModal' data-service='phpmyadmin' data-service_control='uninstall' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle' aria-hidden='true'></span> Uninstall</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link open_phpmyadmin' href='/xE7wqqsr1Etk3grONrnb0nH' target='_blank'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home' aria-hidden='true'></span> Open</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pseudo element` after or before for each `tr` element instead of `border` but also i'm pretty sure there is a way to set `border` for `tr` instead of `td` but not remember right now.

```css
.svlist >tbody> tr {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.table>thead>tr>th, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>td {
    padding: 8px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.svlist >tbody> tr::after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-borderless svlist">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th style='text-align: center;' colspan='3'>Control</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>apache2</td>
            <td>
                <div class='circle'></div>
                <div>Running</div>
            </td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='apache2' data-service_control='restart' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-repeat' aria-hidden='true'></span> Restart</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice disabled' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='apache2' data-service_control='start' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-off' aria-hidden='true'></span> Start</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='apache2' data-service_control='stop' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-stop' aria-hidden='true'></span> Stop</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>monit</td>
            <td>
                <div class='circle'></div>
                <div>Running</div>
            </td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='monit' data-service_control='restart' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-repeat' aria-hidden='true'></span> Restart</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='monit' data-service_control='start' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-off' aria-hidden='true'></span> Start</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice disabled' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='monit' data-service_control='stop' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-stop' aria-hidden='true'></span> Stop</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link uninstall_monit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#UninstallMonitModal' data-service='monit' data-service_control='uninstall' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle' aria-hidden='true'></span> Uninstall</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link open_monit' href='#' target='_blank'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home' aria-hidden='true'></span> Open</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>mysql</td>
            <td>
                <div class='circlered'></div>
                <div>Stopped</div>
            </td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='mysql' data-service_control='restart' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-repeat' aria-hidden='true'></span> Restart</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='mysql' data-service_control='start' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-off' aria-hidden='true'></span> Start</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice disabled' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='mysql' data-service_control='stop' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-stop' aria-hidden='true'></span> Stop</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>php5.6-fpm</td>
            <td>
                <div class='circle'></div>
                <div>Running</div>
            </td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='php5.6-fpm' data-service_control='restart' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-repeat' aria-hidden='true'></span> Restart</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice disabled' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='php5.6-fpm' data-service_control='start' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-off' aria-hidden='true'></span> Start</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='php5.6-fpm' data-service_control='stop' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-stop' aria-hidden='true'></span> Stop</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>php7.0-fpm</td>
            <td>
                <div class='circle'></div>
                <div>Running</div>
            </td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='php7.0-fpm' data-service_control='restart' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-repeat' aria-hidden='true'></span> Restart</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice disabled' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='php7.0-fpm' data-service_control='start' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-off' aria-hidden='true'></span> Start</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link btnservice' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#serviceBasicModal' data-service='php7.0-fpm' data-service_control='stop' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-stop' aria-hidden='true'></span> Stop</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>phpmyadmin</td>
            <td>
                <div class='circle'></div>
                <div>Running</div>
            </td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link uninstall_phpmyadmin' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#UninstallPhpmyadminModal' data-service='phpmyadmin' data-service_control='uninstall' data-sv='finetapir19344'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle' aria-hidden='true'></span> Uninstall</a></td>
            <td align='center' style='width: 100px;'><a class='btn btn-link open_phpmyadmin' href='/xE7wqqsr1Etk3grONrnb0nH' target='_blank'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home' aria-hidden='true'></span> Open</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it broke the other stylesheet. For example, I have 2 tables adjacently placed with max width of each 300 and container which contains them is more than 800px.
By your code it combines lines of both table. [screenshot here](http://prntscr.com/eleb0h)

Comment: Honestly i didn't understand what is the problem, not clear to me but sounds like you can use unique `id` for each table and set my `css` for that table you want. if you can, show me the issue in a fiddle.

Comment: I managed to do it with changes in classes. Thank you @pedram. Saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

These should do the trick

```
.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Didnt work though due to the same problem i described in question.

Comment: Even just the border-collapse alone seems to work fine. Not sure what you mean if this didn't fix it https://jsfiddle.net/ddjgLwq8/